# Code Throwing InvalidOperationException While Setting Text To label Programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1, visual-c#-express-2010

Here Is The Code Which Throws An InvalidOperationExecption Every Time I Try To Set Text To My Label Programmatically...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Project
{
public partial class Splash : Form
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread quit = new Thread(Quit);
        Thread Load = new Thread(LoadIt);
        Load.Start();
        quit.Start();
    }

    private void Splash_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public static void Quit()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public void LoadIt()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Loading.Text = "Loading..";
    }
    }
}
```

Why This Code Throws An Exception? What's Wrong In This?

"Loading" Is The Name Of My Label

[image]

Comment: Because you wrote "Loading.." with only two dots.

Comment: Make sure you are on the main thread, not calling from a background thread or a async task. Controls can only get their properties set while on the main thread, and that's usually why you get this exception.

Comment: The "Additional Information" gives you the reason - you can't set the property of a UI control from a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use the threading dispatcher to execute code on the same thread as the UI

```
Thread.Sleep(500);
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
    Loading.Text = "Loading...";
});
```

Most UI libraries are not thread safe, so you must make UI changes from their own thread.

Comment: I like that you took the time to put 3 dots ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the TPL and use the Task class, this will switch back to the context thread after to resume execution

```
public partial class Splash : Form
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Splash_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Splash_OnLoad(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);

        Loading.Text = "Loading..";

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```